# How to repair small concrete retaining wall

Tags: concrete, crack, retaining-wall

I have a small retaining wall between the walk at the back of the house, and a flower bed. The wall also support small pillars for a roof overhang.

There is a break in the wall, that over the years has started to lean out.

Any thoughts on DIY fixes for this, or is this a problem to take to professionals?

[image]   [image]

[image]   [image]

Comment: Which part isn't plumb—the part by the fence, or the part under the roof?

Answer (score 0):

Ouch

that is more than cosmetic.

Use a strong metal bar and fasten it across the both parts to stop further movement. Do not use flat iron, use L shape or even better U shape that will not bend.

Use concrete and smooth out the crack.